# Outlook Trust Center / Macro Settings greyed out

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, security, macros

Since the last automated update of Office 2019 ( to Microsoft® Outlook® 2019 MSO (Version 2209 Build 16.0.15629.20196) 32-bit) I cannot run my personal macros anymore.

The options in the dialog are greyed out
[Outlook Macro Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k01sF.png)

But this is a personal PC which is not a member of a windows domain and there are no Office 2016 Group Policies present on my Computer.

After a lot of reserach I tried:

- Starting Outlook as Administrator
- Manually setting Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security\adminsecuritymode and Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Security\Level

but nothing helps. Btw its also greyed out in Word and Excel. Before the silent update last night it was working fine for years

Can anyone help?

Thanks,
Wolfgang

Windows 10 21H1

Comment: I'm on MSO 365 version 2209 build 15629.20208 on Win 10.0.19044 21H2 and can confirm that my macro settings are working and not greyed out or disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs into the same issue:

I was able to figure out what was going on. Basically, I am using 2 Microsoft 365 accounts. One from my company and one from one of my customers. The customer one has strict settings set in Microsoft 365 to disable Macros. The one from my company does not have those restrictions.

I was not aware that you can set/overrule local Office settings with Microsft 365 account settings.

Anyway, every time I opened a customer SharePoint document - my active account in Office changed to my customer's 365 account. When I (re)started Outlook, Excel or Word macros were disabled and the settings greyed out. What I had to do was change the active account in the Office Program (you can do this in Word or Excel but not Outlook - at least I couldn't find a way) and then restart the application. All good. Macros settings are enabled again and you can change them.

Very annoying. I don't understand how Microsoft justifies changing those settings on foreign computers (which are not part of the Windows Domain) just by logging in to Microsoft 365.

It took me many frustrating hours to figure that out.

Hope it helps someone else

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested that you could change the GPO as Max Meng mentioned in this thread: [macro settings greyed out](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/7c3d637d-453d-4a84-ac44-c1500bed95f4/macro-settings-greyed-out).

Comment: I can't find any Office Group Policies under User Configuration/Administrative Templates/...

Comment: Have you installed Administrative Templates (.admx)? (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/103667)

Comment: Yes I did it.The group policies are all showing up now. I set the"Secuity setting for macros" and "Outlook Security Mode" group policies and did a "gpupdate /force" but the issue is still there

Comment: Does this issue occur in other computers?

Comment: No it doesn't. Only on one